# AuthGG C++ Unresolved Extern Symbols

Tags: c++, authentication

I've been trying to use the AuthGG native C++ example, and when i try to call the UrlDownloadToFileA function, i keep getting unresolved external symbols. The example uses cryptopp library, etc.

Code:

```
#include <urlmon.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

my linker input options: urlmon.lib

UrlDownloadToFileA(0, "https://localhost/test.txt","C:\\test.txt",0,0);
```

Thanks guys :)

Comment: The correct spelling is `URLDownloadToFileA` (but maybe that's just a typo in your question).  In any event, please add the error message (verbatim, as text) to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I already tried @ÖöTiib

Comment: Tried what? How it went? It is link to useful collection of possible causes and ways to resolve that linker error.